# how to generate unique id like facebook, google+ in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra, uuid

I'm using nodeJS and cassandra

I'm currently using UUID v1 as unique id

but, I think uuid is too long

I want to generate numeric unique id like fb and G+, which is shorter

and don't have to check if the id exist in DB or not before insert

example:

> https://plus.google.com/104560124403688998123/posts
>
> facebook/100001458264256

I'm thinking of generate it base on some user detail?

any good idea?

Comment: What *are* your user details?

Comment: Define "too long". There are some pretty short hash functions which might do the job for you.

Comment: @Deestan maybe some data in request?
and parse them to base10

Comment: @KingCronus I want some numeric id, maybe about 20 chars long, but UUID got 32 chars long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating your colum families with UUID types, they will be stored in binary, and only require 16 bytes on disk, which is already less than the 20 bytes you want.

Look at the [cql docs](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html),

```
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY MonkeyTypes (
    KEY uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    species text,
    alias text,
    population varint
)
```

You can use a database, [zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) or [snowflake](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/06/announcing-snowflake.html) to generate unique 8 byte ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [flake-idgen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flake-idgen) package to get the shorter unique ID.

```
var FlakeIdGen = require('flake-idgen')
var intformat = require('biguint-format')
var generator = new FlakeIdGen;
var id1 = generator.next();
var id2 = generator.next();
var id3 = intformat(id1, 'dec'); //sample : 5829986774188818434
var id4 = intformat(id2, 'hex', {prefix:'0x'}) // sample : 0x50e8461520c00003
```